# Script JS transform array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi guys I have a little question about a script and a way to get an output format like :

```
hierarchicalCategories.lvl0 : Womens  
hierarchicalCategories.lvl1 : Womens > Accessories  
hierarchicalCategories.lvl2 : Womens > Accessories > Bags  
hierarchicalCategories.lvl3 : Womens > Accessories > Bags > Sport- & Travel Bags
```

My array is simply : ["Womens", "Accessories", "Bags", "Sport- & Travel Bags"]
So I tried to code a function and get my expected data but, I'm blocked on how get my current postion and the first postitions of my array until the begining.

```
let categories = ["Womens", "Accessories", "Bags", "Sport- & Travel Bags"];
let rootName = "hierarchicalCategories.lvl";

const reindexFunction = () => {
  let current_position = 0;
  let size = categories.length;
  for (current_position; current_position < size; current_position++) {
    let first = rootName + current_position;
    if (current_position !== 0) {
      let categ =
        categories[current_position - 1] +
        " " +
        ">" +
        " " +
        categories[current_position];
      console.log(first+":"+categ);
    } else {
      let categ = categories[current_position];
      console.log(first+":"+categ);
    }
  }
};

reindexFunction();
```

The result of this is:

```
hierarchicalCategories.lvl0:Womens
hierarchicalCategories.lvl1:Womens > Accessories
hierarchicalCategories.lvl2:Accessories > Bags
hierarchicalCategories.lvl3:Bags > Sport- & Travel Bags
```

I'm sure it's easy but I searched some method to make this I found nothing.
Thank you for your help, tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate over the categories and get the categories from index 0 to the current index. I used the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) methods of arrays:

- iterate over the categories with **forEach**
- get the items from index 0 to the current index with **slice**
- format the slice to the desired format with **join**

**Note:** [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log) adds a space between each argument by default

```js
let categories = ["Womens", "Accessories", "Bags", "Sport- & Travel Bags"];
let rootName = "hierarchicalCategories.lvl";

categories.forEach((c, i) => console.log(rootName+i, ':', categories.slice(0, i+1).join(' > ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straight-forward solution coming to me mind would be to map the indexes of the `categories` array to strings that are built from joining all elements of the array up to the index.

I'm doing this using `Array.prototype.map` and utilizing the *second* argument it passes to the callback function, which is the index. The first argument would be the value itself, but we are not interested in that, that's why I called it `_` and it's not used.

I'm not sure about the exact output format desired - you said *transform* array, so I assume the result should be another array. But in case that's not the case, is should be easy to adjust.

```js
const categories = ['Womens', 'Accessories', 'Bags', 'Sport- & Travel Bags']
const rootName = 'hierarchicalCategories.lvl'

function buildHierarchicalCategories (categories) {
  return categories.map((_, i) =>
    `${rootName}${i} : ${categories.slice(0, i + 1).join(' > ')}`
  )
}

console.log(buildHierarchicalCategories(categories))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just keep the categories and add to them

```js
let categories = ["Womens", "Accessories", "Bags", "Sport- & Travel Bags"];
let rootName = "hierarchicalCategories.lvl";
let level = "";
categories.map((e, index) => {
  level += e;
  console.log(rootName + index + " : " + level);
  level += " > ";
});
```